# phpmyadmin do not run with ubuntu 18

Tags: apache, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I went from 16 to 18 ubuntu and since my phpmyadmin no longer works;

http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ give this : read the joint file [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1XSX.png)

my apache2 works: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ return the home page : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq2OA.png)

on the other hand php http://localhost/phpinfo.php returns a blank page

thanks for  help.